RIP Kris Kristofferson - Star of Blade Trilogy and country music legend
Remembering Grammy Award Winning Kris Kristofferson, who passed away at age 88.
Better known for his country music success, but has graced the screens in movies such as A Star Is Born, but best known to us for his role in the Blade Trilogy as "Abraham Whistler".

Farewell.
